# Windows Service app in .NET hangs on "Starting" when started, it won't stop either

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, .net-4.5

I am writing a simple windows service to learn. This is my project structure:

[image]

**WindowsService.cs**

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ServiceTest
{
    class WindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Public Constructor for WindowsService.
        /// - Put all of your Initialization code here.
        /// </summary>
        EventLog serviceEventLog;
        public WindowsService()
        {
            // Configure service event logging
            serviceEventLog = new EventLog();
            this.AutoLog = false;
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MyApp"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyApp", "ServiceTest");
            }
            serviceEventLog.Source = "MyApp";
            serviceEventLog.Log = "ServiceTest";

            // Configure service properties
            this.ServiceName = "My Windows Service";
            this.EventLog.Log = "ServiceTest";

            // List of events this service can handle
            this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
            this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.CanShutdown = true;
            this.CanStop = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Main Thread: This is where your Service is Run.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new WindowsService());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose of objects that need it here.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">Whether
        ///    or not disposing is going on.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Custom code

            // Run parent code
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnStart(): Put startup code here
        ///  - Start threads, get inital data, etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            serviceEventLog.WriteEntry("Service Started");

            base.OnStart(args);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnStop(): Put your stop code here
        /// - Stop threads, set final data, etc.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            serviceEventLog.WriteEntry("Service Stopped");

            base.OnStop();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnPause: Put your pause code here
        /// - Pause working threads, etc.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            serviceEventLog.WriteEntry("Service Paused");

            base.OnPause();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnContinue(): Put your continue code here
        /// - Un-pause working threads, etc.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            serviceEventLog.WriteEntry("Service Resumed");

            base.OnContinue();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnShutdown(): Called when the System is shutting down
        /// - Put code here when you need special handling
        ///   of code that deals with a system shutdown, such
        ///   as saving special data before shutdown.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            serviceEventLog.WriteEntry("Service Shutdown");

            base.OnShutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

**WindowsServiceInstaller.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ServiceTest
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Public Constructor for WindowsServiceInstaller.
        /// - Put all of your Initialization code here.
        /// </summary>
        public WindowsServiceInstaller()
        {
            ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller =
                               new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            //# Service Account Information
            serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

            //# Service Information
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "My New C# Windows Service";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

            //# This must be identical to the WindowsService.ServiceBase name
            //# set in the constructor of WindowsService.cs
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "My Windows Service";

            this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }
}
```

**install.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX4=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX4%

echo Installing ServiceTest...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /i "%~dp0ServiceTest.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
echo Done.
@PAUSE
```

I ran the `install.bat` script as `Administrator` and the service installed. When I click start, It's stuck on starting:

[image]

If I right click the service and click `Stop`, I get the following:

[image]

I am on Windows 10 using .NET Framework 4.5. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I successfully started and then stopped the service after installation on a Windows 7 with .net framework 4.5. Can you try to put a Debugger.Break() on top of OnStart() ?

Comment: Simply attach Visual Studio to the service process, hit "pause" and check the callstack for the thread processing the "start" request